# ASP.NET C# get list of valid domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns

Is there any way to query a list of valid domains from ASP.NET C#, similar to the list shown when logging into widows? I would like to provide this to the client users so they can select the appropriate domain with which to login to an intranet web application. I've tried using Forest.GetCurrentForest but I always seem to only get one domain back, when I definitely know there are others.

UPDATE: (CODE)

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;


namespace Domains {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

      try {
        using (Forest forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest()) {
          Console.WriteLine("FOREST");
          Console.WriteLine("  {0}", forest.Name);
          Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
          Console.WriteLine("    DOMAINS");
          foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains) {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("      {0}", domain.Name));
            Console.WriteLine("        TRUSTS");
            TrustRelationshipInformationCollection domainTrusts = domain.GetAllTrustRelationships();
            if (domainTrusts.Count == 0) {
              Console.WriteLine("          N/A");
            } else {
              foreach (TrustRelationshipInformation trust in domainTrusts) {
                DirectoryContext x = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, trust.TargetName);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("          {0} -> {1}", trust.SourceName, trust.TargetName));
              }
            }
            domain.Dispose();
          }
          Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
          Console.WriteLine("    TRUSTS");
          TrustRelationshipInformationCollection forestTrusts = forest.GetAllTrustRelationships();
          if (forestTrusts.Count == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("      N/A");
          } else {
            foreach (TrustRelationshipInformation trust in forestTrusts) {
              Console.WriteLine(String.Format("      {0} -> {1}", trust.SourceName, trust.TargetName));
            }
          }
        }
      }


      catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("\nPress ESC to exit...");
      do {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
          // Do something
        }
      } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);


    }
  }
}
```

Now when I go to log into the machine directly (remote desktop, etc.) I get a list of 6 domains I can log into, but when the above code runs on the same machine (currently just a console app for testing, not ASP.NET enabled yet), I get one domain, the current domain I'm logged into on the machine.

EDIT:
  I think maybe I'm getting confused, perhaps what I am really looking for is the NetBios domain names. Because I just realized the domain + all the trusts equal the count of domains I'm looking for, but these are the full names, not short names I expected.

UPDATE:
  So I was able to acquire the netbiosname of the main domains using an LDAP query, but I'm not sure how to go about getting the netbiosname for the trusted domains...

Comment: It should work. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all domains in teh forest use:

```
Forest.Domains
```

property. returns a DomainCollection.

`GetCurrentForest` returns only Forest for the current user context.

```
Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains
```

Should return all domains.